# Can not set onItemClickListener to CheckBox in custom ListView

Tags: android

I have a cutsom ListView and custom ArrayAdapter. My ListView contains TextView and CheckBox. I want to implement onClick() method on CheckBox.

custom_ListView.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_inList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_inList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
private List<Task> tasks;
private Activity context;

private DataBase dataBase;
private Task task;


// Constructor
public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<Task> tasks){
    super(context,R.layout.list_with_checkbox,tasks);
    this.context=context;
    this.tasks=tasks;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int postion, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_with_checkbox, null, true);

    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_inList);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //position should be equal to the position of CheckBox that is clicked 
            Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(postion),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

And problem is that when I run this app, I've found that when I click any of the CheckBoxes of ListView, Toast message shows only the last position of the list. In other words , I can't get position of CheckBox that is clicked in ListView. Also I've tried to implement onItemClickListener() in MainActivity , but it did not react on CheckBox click instead it reacted on TextView click.

Comment: put your checkBox on global variable then try onItemClickListener()

Comment: @Istiak I've already tried it, did not work, ListView.onItemClickListener only reacts when TextView is clicked not CheckBox

Comment: Had you considered migrating to RecyclerView? The RecyclerView is build to remove the ListView#onItemClickListener and allow the View for the item handle its events.